# Find selected language LCID after changing display language

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 machine that has had several languages installed using
   Control Panel
   Region and Language
   Keyboards and Languages
   Install/Uninstall languages

When I change the display language using
   Control Panel
   Region and Language
   Keyboards and Languages
   Choose a display language
everything displays correctly.

I need to read which language has been selected.
The registry entries I have found all point to the original language (0409) English - United States not the selected language (0404) Chinese - Taiwan.

Does anyone know how to find the selected language LCID?
If I can get the LCID I can display the language selected in English (which is my ultimate goal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

As Mark Ransom suggested, you can use `GetUserDefaultLCID`

```
int wmain()
{
    LCID lcid = GetUserDefaultLCID();//LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;
    cout << "lcid: " << lcid << endl;
    wchar_t buf[100];
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, buf, 100)) wcout << buf << endl;
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE, buf, 100)) wcout << buf << endl;
    if (GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, buf, 100)) wcout << buf << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output on my Windows 8:

```
lcid: 1028
0404
Chinese (Traditional)
zh
```

Also if user changed system's language in the middle of program run, then `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message is sent to application:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Following that link and diving deeper leads to [`GetUserDefaultLCID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318135(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `GetUserDefaultLCID` makes more sense. The link I gave was for when user changes the system language in the middle of program run, that's not very practical anyway.

Comment: I was eager to try GetUserDefaultLCID but it has the same problem all my registry attempts have had. it returns the 'default' (i.e. original installed) LCID which in my case is (0409) not the (0404) that is obviously the current selected display language.

Comment: What if you change the language to German or French something? I recall Chinese is sometimes not installed by default.

Comment: I have tried the code Barmak put in his answer and I still get the original (0409).  I am using Windows 7 but I dont think that is the problem.  question for Barmak, did you select a display language in Control panel that is different from the default Windows installation language or was the (0404) chinese the install language?

Comment: Barmak, as for the German or French question.  In Control panel the only options I have are the original English and the Chinese languages I added in Control panel / Region and Language / Keyboards and Languages / Install/Uninstall languages...

Comment: Steve, I just go to Region setting, select language under "Format" tab. It doesn't need restart. It's also called "Change date, time, or number format". I don't know if this method is right or wrong, but it gets LCID to cooperate.

Comment: Barmak,  I see the problem,  you are changing the format for Dates and Times from English to Chinese.  That is not what I am doing.  The Machine has windows installed using english so the display language is english.  What I am changing is the Display Language on the Control Panel / Keyboards and Languages tab / and select Chinese as the Display Language.  This causes Windows to display all text as Chinese. not just the Chinese default date and time format with english text.

Comment: Oh sorry, try `LCID lcid = LOWORD(GetKeyboardLayout(0))`

Comment: Barmak,  still not working LCID lcid = LOWORD(GetKeyboardLayout(0)) returns the english 0404.  Also Not sure why keyboard layout would have anything to do with the Display language character set.

Comment: You can also try `GetSystemDefaultLCID()` If regional settings, keyboard and everything else is set to English then maybe it's English. I can't really think of anything else.

Comment: By the way there is also `GetUserDefaultUILanguage()`, it returns for example 1033 for English, 1036 for French  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx